# text alignment in twitter-bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, text-alignment

On my website, I am putting google map to show my location.
I figured out with google map API without any difficult.
My problem is that I write my phone number and address beside this google map, but it always show below google map. I tried couple of different bootstrap grid components, but no luck with me.

```
<section id="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                <hr class="star-primary">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
              <div id='map'></div>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <div>123-4567-8910
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Line 6 is custom CSS that shows star mark middle of hr line.
Some components I tried worked, but then my contact information is right beside map without any space.
What can I do with this?
Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0):

You can style in two column

```
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
          <div id='map'></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            123-4567-8910
        </div>
    </div>
```

or you a float left  (with span inside divinside the )

```
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
          <div id='map'></div>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <div style="float-left" > span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt" aria-hidden="true">123-4567-8910</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Otherwise check if your page / tag are well formed (correctly nested, open/closed)

Comment: I used both and both didn't work. They are overlapped my map. Do you think it is because my map is too big? (it is width 400px and height 300px). Thank you for your advice though!

Comment: how much is wide your device?

Comment: I am using 15inch laptop. But I am also resizing my browser big and small to test.

Comment: What happen in your code  is not  normal for bootstrap. please provide all the html code .. please

Comment: and I add google map on the contact us area instead of its own contact form. Sorry, since my html contains private information, I am putting theme I use.

Comment: Can you post the css style for your map and for the related div ..?

Comment: sure. it is https://github.com/misonam03/startbootstrap-freelancer/blob/gh-pages/css/freelancer.css I added my map div as width:120% height: 300px.

Comment: I don't see nothings weird ... then check if you tag are well formed.. i have added this comment also to the answer ..

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I figured out. I add text-center class in side of div attribute and it seems it works.

Comment: For the future, if anyone has problem that contents overlap, add empty <div class=" **choice of your bootstrap grid class**"

Comment: But have use some of my suggestion or nothing?

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work on mine. I don't know why